# JQuery Mobile Dynamic Button add Click

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an infowindow in a google map like so,

```
var content = '<div id="link"><input type="button" value="Report this light" id="reportBtn"/></div>';
```

i am using jquery mobile to bind a 'click' event when the infowindow pops open on the map but it doens't fire, my code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
 $('#reportBtn').on('click', function() {
     alert('it works');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation. Try

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#reportBtn', function() {
        alert('it works');
    });
});
```

Instead of `document` you can use nearest static element that is a parent to `<div id="link">`.

```
$('#nearestparent').on('click', '#reportBtn', function() {...});
```